# aiohttp/_websocket.c(1475): warning C4996: 'Py_OptimizeFlag': deprecated in 3.12

Tags: python, pip, aiohttp

So I am trying to make my own Ai and for that I was installing open Ai when the following error occurrred :ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I used the command pip install openai on pycharm